# Need help passing date with events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In short. I have a tunnel building game where every tunnel piece has a `Vector2 ChunkedPostion` that generally describes where they are located in world space.

The problem is I need to Recalculate some things when one of these tunnels is destroyed and it would take longer than necessary to reload the whole map. Therefore, I'm hoping someone could tell me how to pass along this `Chunkedpostion` in an event that's called on the destruction of a tunnel so each tunnel could quickly check if the event is relevant to them before making the calculations.

simplified code:

```
public class transmitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void SendSignel();
    public static event SendSignel OnSendSignel;

    Vector2 ChunkedPostion;

    private void Start()
    {
        ChunkedPostion = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {
            OnSendSignel();//<= i would like to pass along ChunkedPostion in the Event 
        }
    }
} 

public class receiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    //and then have someway to "Debug.Log" the recieved coordinates

    private void OnEnable() { transmitter.OnSendSignel += PrintSignel; }
    private void OnDisable() { transmitter.OnSendSignel -= PrintSignel; }

    void PrintSignel()
    {
        Debug.Log("received");
    }

}
```

Comment: What's stopping you passing that value in your event?

Comment: I dont know how to.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code so that we have a chance to understand what your issue might possibly be? I don't really get why you can't simply add an extra parameter to your event delegate, or an extra property to your event arguments.

Comment: @0neManshooter If you have solved your question, you can write an answer for it below.

Comment: @0neManshooter If you have solved your question, **do not edit the answer into the question**.  There is a large empty space below these comments where you can post your answer.

Comment: @Liama despite how uninformative your first Comment was I appreciate your help in showing me how simple the answer really was.

Answer (score 1):

Working Code:

```
public class transmitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public delegate void SendSignel();
    public delegate void SendSignel(Vector2 SenderPostion);
    public static event SendSignel OnSendSignel;

    Vector2 ChunkedPostion;

    private void Start()
    {
        ChunkedPostion = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
    }

    void Update()
    {   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {
            OnSendSignel(ChunkedPostion);//<= i would like to pass along ChunkedPostion in the Event 
        }
    }
}

public class receiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    //and then have someway to "Debug.Log" the recieved coordinates

    private void OnEnable() { transmitter.OnSendSignel += PrintSignel; }
    private void OnDisable() { transmitter.OnSendSignel -= PrintSignel; }

    //void PrintSignel()
    //{
    //    Debug.Log("received");
    //}

    void PrintSignel(Vector2 SenderPostion)
    {
        Debug.Log("received");
        Debug.Log("at: " + SenderPostion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong syntax, at least in the question you are.

```
    public static event SendSignel OnSendSignel;
    //should be 
    public static event EventHandler<Vector2> OnSendSignal
```

using this you'll be able to provide OnSendSignal a vector2 when you invoke it